# Are IIS configuration tasks on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question was recently asked and answered: [Use https on asp.net application running on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44051583/3932049).

Given the accepted answer, it is pretty clear that the question is completely unrelated to programming, since the answer is, practically "**you need to configure IIS correctly**".

I would consider it to be on-topic, should the question have been about **IIS Express**, which we do require to program ASP.NET websites; but since it is regarding **IIS**, should it be considered on-topic?

Comment: You can use IIS Express or IIS to program .NET websites.  I'd say the answer is a poor answer, but in general questions relating to IIS are on-topic.

Comment: I would say that IIS is "software commonly used by programmers", especially when configuring it for localhost. If the question had been "Use https for ASP.NET application in production" I might be less sanguine about that though.

Comment: It's not a "problem that is unique to software development", heck, it's at most a web admin problem. just because you find the problem and you are programmer doesn't mean that you should ask on SO!

Comment: @Braiam that's what I believe. Common developers don't have access to production servers (where you normally configure SSL), or even the certificates to install them. That's an infrastructure task at best

Comment: It's not a great question, but I beg to differ. Not every developer runs websites on a Datacenter. And this is explicitly about running a website from Visual Studio. Do you expect a server admin to know where to go in Visual Studio and change the web server configuration? Would a server admin know to explain that IIS Express can't open port 443 unless you run VS under an Admin account or you enable it via the command line? There is a grey area to be sure, but I think this is within the realm of SO scope.

Comment: @EuroMicelli please explain me how binding port 59917 to an HTTPS binding configuration in IIS is at all related to Visual Studio or IIS Express. The OP explicitly says "I'm trying to run the application over https", not "I am trying to debug the application over HTTPs when deployed to IIS"